# How do I map this URL to a Spring controller method?

Tags: spring, controller, httpwebrequest, mapping

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I'm having fits mapping URLs to controller methods.  I would like to map the URL "/my-context-path/organizations/add" to the controller method below.  In my controller, I have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/organizations")
public class OrganizationController
{

    …
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doGetadd()
    {
        … do some stuff …
        return new ModelAndView("organizations/add");
    }   // doGetadd
```

In my web.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>SB Admin</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/organizations/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and in my dispathcer-servlet.xml I have

```
...
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.myco.subco" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

but requests for my desired context-path result in "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/organizations/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher" errors (using JBoss 7).  How do I map this thing properly?  Note that I have multiple methods in my controller that I want to different URLs within the "/organizations" space.

Comment: try after understanding this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184411/friendly-url-mapping-issues-java-spring

Comment: what is that mycontext-path you mentioned...some of your words are confusing to me...Anyway Usha answer can help you a lot because of removing the * in the url and the reason is that if you put * it also include the includes to pick the dispatcher which means loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Change the dispatcher servlet mapping to :

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And for the OrganizationController the mapping would be

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/organizations")
    public class OrganizationController
```

And for the ContractsController the mapping would be

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/contracts")
    public class OrganizationController
```

Comment: Holy God that worked!  So simple, but I was searching for that forever.  I'm voting for you for president today.

Comment: Glad that it worked! Vote for the president if you haven't already :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) the ModelAndView constructor parameter is the name of the view file.

So that file could be `addView.jsp` .

As well as the fact that you're (as far as my Spring knowledge goes) actually mapping it to /Application-Name/organizations/organizations/add due to :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/organizations/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/organizations")
public class OrganizationController
```

I'd recommend changing the requestmapping from the controller to

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class OrganizationController
```

The `<url-pattern>/organizations/</url-pattern>` basiccally defines the 'virtual path' on which your site will be accessible.
Al mappings you do on controllers will append to it, makeing it /organizations/whateverpagecomeshere.jsp

And make sure that View file exists !

Comment: I want to make sure I'm understanding you correctly.  For all controllers, you're recommending I put the "@RequestMapping("/")" before the "@Controller" annotation?  I also have a ContractsController whose URLs I want to map to "/contracts/add", "/contracts/update" and so on.  Will your suggestion work for multiple controllers?

Comment: @Dave As a side note, please address the message, that way I get notified of your reply :-) It is exactly the other way around  the answer Usha gave. I choose to let your context be /organizations/whateverpagecomeshere.derp , and that way, by assigning the `@RequestMapping` to "/" you would actually be asigning to /organizations/ .. Without having it in your controller. That means for your 2nd question you'd be asigning to /organizations/contracts/add.extension . You see the value of the url pattern at the servlet-mapping ?