# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet HelloWeb is not available

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have been learning spring mvc, but I get error page "HTTP Status 404 - Servlet HelloWeb is not available" when I started tomcat server and went to URL `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/student`. What's wrong with my code or structure, how fix this? Thanks for help!

# web.xml:

Spring MVC Form Handling

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

# HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You've mapped the HelloWeb servlet to the url "/", so the url youre trying to access should look like http://localhost:8080/ instead.

Comment: How you mapped in your controller class? can you show us your controller class?

Comment: @limelights / indicates that any url mapping with anyvalue has to go to dispatcher-servlet.xml(In this case Helloweb-servlet.xml) and it goes to component-scan with all controllers for knowing the url mapping(using annotations in controllers)...

Comment: Do you have a Controller mapped to the /student request?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a url pattern like /* instead of /. A / as url pattern means only requests to default root `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb` will be served by your servlet

Comment: this is wrong..mentioning it will give this problem..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184411/friendly-url-mapping-issues-java-spring